# Parallel four task execution

Tags: java, parallel-processing, aes, executorservice

I want to execute four task parallel using four thread independently.I want to reduce execution time. But this program can not reduce execution time. In this program the sequential execution time is smaller than parallel execution time.I want to faster execute program from sequential execution. How can i four task execute parallel and reduce execution time. please remove problem of this code and give the solution.

```
package TestParallel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

/**
 *
 * @author Sohel Rana
 */
public class Executor {

    public void encrypt(File fname) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(256);  //using AES-256
        SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();  //generating key
        //  System.out.println("Key = " + bytesToHex(key.getEncoded()));
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");  //getting cipher for AES
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);  //initializing cipher for encryption with key

        //creating file output stream to write to file
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fname + ".aes")) {
            //creating object output stream to write objects to file
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(key);  //saving key to file for use during decryption

            //creating file input stream to read contents for encryption
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname)) {
                //creating cipher output stream to write encrypted contents
                try (CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, aesCipher)) {
                    int read;
                    byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
                    while ((read = fis.read(buf)) != -1) //reading from file
                    {
                        cos.write(buf, 0, read);  //encrypting and writing to file
                    }
                }
            }
            //  fname.delete();
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Sohel Rana\\Desktop\\test\\33 - Overflow Menu.mp4");
        File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Sohel Rana\\Desktop\\test\\Java Cryptography Tutorials 1 AES Encryption and Decryption using Java.mp4");
        File file3 = new File("C:\\Users\\Sohel Rana\\Desktop\\test\\30 - Dank Meme Bro.mp4");
        File file4 = new File("C:\\Users\\Sohel Rana\\Desktop\\test\\How to change API level Android Studio.mp4");

        Executor ex = new Executor();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        pool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                ex.encrypt(file1);
                ex.encrypt(file2);
                 ex.encrypt(file3);
                ex.encrypt(file4);
            } catch (Exception ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(Executor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
        });

        pool.shutdown();

        if (!pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)) {
            System.err.println("Pool did not terminate.");
        }
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Paralle took time " + (endTime - startTime)
                + " milliseconds.");

    }
}
```

Comment: You're submitting a single task of encrypting four files, not four tasks of encrypting a single file.

Comment: Sir this program is right?Please confirm it sir.

Comment: How can  I four task submit four file encrypt in parallel

Answer (score 3):

This is creating one `Runnable` which runs the individual `encrypt`s one after the other.

```
    pool.execute(() -> {
        try {
            ex.encrypt(file1);
            ex.encrypt(file2);
            ex.encrypt(file3);
            ex.encrypt(file4);
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(Executor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    });
```

What you need to do is something like

```
for (File f : new File[] { file1, file2, file3, file4}) {
    pool.execute(() -> {
        try {
            ex.encrypt(f);
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(Executor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    });
}
```

As a side note, the way you wait for the threads to finish works only because the size of the tread pool is large enough to start all submitted tasks. If you were to extend this solution to add more file, those may never get encoded because the executor has them in the queue but not started yet; which means they won't be started at all, because that's one of the effects of calling `shutdown` on the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: I want to run all file parallel not sequential run...please help for parallel execute all file and reduce execution time

Comment: @Sohel The tasks are **submitted sequentially** to the executor service, but are **executed in parallel**.

Comment: How can i submitted all task parallel and execute parallel ?

Comment: You could create another thread pool that starts four threads, they all wait on a signal or whatever, then the main thread raises the signal and all four threads will hopefully submit the main tasks in parallel. This is obviously a pointless waste of effort; print out the time at the start of the loop, and you'll no doubt see less than a millisecond between the submission of each task.

Comment: @Sohel "submitting in parallel" is utterly pointless. First, submitting them only takes a millisecond so it won't gain anything from concurrency. What's more, the `ExecutorService` you're submitting to will need to protect the critical section in which the concurrent submissions arrive, which will result in the end point being sequential anyway. It would just be putting in work to pointlessly parallelize something that required work to sequentialize properly.